# consecutive date: date change every day in a saved record

Tags: python, date, datetime, odoo-14, odoo-15

create a datetime field in odoo studio that shows the current date when the record is created, I need that when I return to that record it always shows me the current date instead of the date the record was created

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem

when changing the widget from a date time to remaining_days it automatically counts the days

Answer (score -1):

yes there is built in field is: create_date

Comment: the create_date field shows me the date the record was created, what I need is for it to always be updated to today's date every time I go to see it

Comment: can you explain your question clear